# What is the lifetime/scope of ClientInterceptorContext in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, .net-4.6, grpc-dotnet

I have a .NET gRPC client on .net 4.6.2 using `Grpc.Core` library.

I've registered gRPC channel as singleton to reuse it following [this recommendation].(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#reuse-grpc-channels)

There's how I create an instance of the channel:

```cs
public static InvokerAndChannel<T> CreateGrpcCallInvokerAndChannel<T>(
    string endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    where T : class
{
    var licenseCode = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILicenseCodeResolver>().GetLicenseCode();

    var channel = new Channel(endpoint, credentials, new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxSendMessageLength, "1mb").Yield());
    var callInvoker = channel
        .Intercept(
            new ClientTracingInterceptor(
                new ClientTracingInterceptorOptions { RecordMessageEvents = false }))
        .Intercept(new StaticMetadataInterceptor(licenseCode));

    return new InvokerAndChannel<T>(callInvoker, channel);
}
```

As you can see the pipeline includes `StaticMetadataInterceptor` which adds license header to the call. Effectively it's also a singleton.

I have multiple parallel calls to various methods of the same gRPC service. And I see that `StaticMetadataInterceptor` receives same `ClientInterceptorContext`. At least `context.Options.Headers` keeps growing, so after several calls it contains the same header several times. **Why?**

Here's the code for the interceptor:

```
internal sealed class StaticMetadataInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly string _licenseCode;

    public StaticMetadataInterceptor(string licenseCode)
    {
        _licenseCode = licenseCode;
    }

    private void ExtendMetadata<TRequest, TResponse>(ref ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context)
            where TRequest : class
            where TResponse : class
    {
        var metadata = context.Options.Headers;
        if (metadata == null)
        {
            metadata = new Metadata();
            context = new ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse>(context.Method, context. Host, context.Options.WithHeaders(metadata));
        }

        metadata.Add(GrpcStandardMetadataKeys.License, _licenseCode);
    }

    public override TResponse BlockingUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ExtendMetadata(ref context);

        return continuation(request, context);
    }

    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ExtendMetadata(ref context);

        return continuation(request, context);
    }

    public override AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse> AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncClientStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ExtendMetadata(ref context);

        return continuation(context);
    }

    public override AsyncServerStreamingCall<TResponse> AsyncServerStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncServerStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ExtendMetadata(ref context);

        return continuation(request, context);
    }

    public override AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse> AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncDuplexStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ExtendMetadata(ref context);

        return continuation(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but could be because the gRPC services are transient (I think thats the default way) on the server side? So whenever you send a call to a gRPC service, a new instance of that service is instantiated on the server -> new header? I think you are still reusing the gRPC channel, so in theory you are doing everything right?

Comment: @dan-kli, but this issue is in the client side. Interceptor adds multiple headers.

Comment: Yes, but my point was when the server creates a new service instance for each call, a new header will be there on the client side for each call? If that makes sense?

Comment: I am not getting it,TBH. The header is set by the client for Client -> Server calls.

Comment: Yes, and you need a new header for each call, then the call arrives on the server and creates a new service instance. So it makes sense that a new header is created, right? Why do you expect to only have one header when you reuse a gRPC channel?

Comment: > So it makes sense that a new header is created, right?
Created where? 

I've added the code of the interceptor.

Comment: You asked the following: *At least `context.Options.Headers` keeps growing, so after several calls it contains the same header several times. Why?* Each call creates a new header that is intercepted by your interceptor, and the interceptor is registered for a single gRPC channel in which all the calls take place (as a singleton). Why would you expect anything else to happen than the amount of headers increasing with each call?

Comment: Also sorry for my first comment, it (most likely) does not matter at all if the services are transient or not on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, why headers collection kept growing.

Generated Grpc client has an optional parameter of `Metada` type. My assumption was that items from this collection will be copied, and if interceptor adds headers to the outgoing request, initial metadata won't be affected. That assumption was wrong.

Example:

```
var metadata = new Metadata();
client.CallFoo(request, metadata);
```

If interceptor adds headers to request, `metadata` will be changed.